# Java Filechooser showMultipleDiaglogue add files in order?

Tags: java, filechooser, dialog

Is there a way select multiple files and have them added to a list **in the order that you clicked?** I know how to select multiple files, but they usually just get added in alphabetic order.

Answer (score 1):

No, the filechooser doesn't have this functionality by default (why would it?).

You could take the source to filechooser and add this functionality in your own version of it, but this definitely seems like a corner case to me.

Comment: To add this functionality would I have to use action listeners? Will those work within a fileChooser dialogue?